# codigneter setcookie doesn't work in my case

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['fb_userId'])){
    setcookie('fb_userId', $userId);
}
```

I put this within one of my controller, the cookie named userId should be inserted after the call right? but I checked the resources tab of my chrome, I don't see anything..

I also tried the helper method like this

```
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie_arr);
```

Comment: I think you mean if(!isset ...

Comment: As above, this will only set the cookie if a cookie of the same name already exists.

Comment: Which will never happen obviously (in this context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set cookie in Codeigniter than you can use that code

```
 $this->load->helper('cookie');
     $cookie = array(
       'name'   => 'testcookie',
       'value'  => 'test value',
       'expire' => '86500'
      );

     $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

     echo $_COOKIE['testcookie'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, it will only set the cookie if the same cookie name *(fb_userId)* already exists.

Try use the following code:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['fb_userId'])){
   setcookie('fb_userId', $userId);
}
```

I've add the **!** before your `isset()`